# SOAP API calls from .net to retrieve Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, email-template, content, content-builder

I am trying to retrieve the Orientation (layout- HTML only, free form, etc) of Content Area in Marketing Cloud via SOAP API calls.

Call that I am making

```
var rr = new ServiceReference_SOAPClient.RetrieveRequest()         rr.ObjectType = "ContentArea";
 rr.Properties = new string[] { "ID", "Name", "Content","Layout"};
```

Layout is giving me just two option: Raw text and HTML wrapper; not showing any of the 5 orientations (layouts) while creating the content.

Answer (score 0):

The Orientation Layout (HTML, Free Form etc) are not available in SOAP or REST API. If you create a content area via API, it is always "free form" type.

The only three values for layout types are:
HTMLWrapped, RawText, SMS

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contentarea.htm